# Task list not visible in internet explorer - Internet explorer settings on server

Tags: 2013, permissions, task-list

I created a task list with the system account. This task list is not visible to other accounts. What could be the reason for this ? 
The Urls are the same and the second account (Jürgen Stürmer) has admin rights as well but is no systemaccount. I thought maybe the list is checked out but it seems there is no way to check out a task list.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Added. As you can see "Jürgen Stürmer" has full control but it is still not visible

Comment: Hmm, after some testing, it seems to be an issue of IE. Works in firefox...

Comment: which IE version are you using ? [Plan browser support in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx)

Comment: its IE 10 on the server.

Comment: Do you have any extra add-ons installed on IE 10..?

Comment: No, Nothing... 
Finally got it to work. The site has to be in the trusted pool of you internet explorer. Also, Active x and JS permissions has to be enabled.#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site has to be in the trusted pool of you internet explorer. Also, Active x and JS permissions has to be enabled. *(By [Jürgen Stürmer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/15067/jurgen-sturmer)])*

Add your SharePoint site to trusted and try this as well [PROBLEMS WITH INTERNET EXPLORER 10 (IE10) AND SHAREPOINT](http://corypeters.net/2012/10/problems-with-ie10-and-sharepoint/)

Also, disable extra add-ons (if any)

Comment: Simple but saved my time lot. Its good if shared exact IE option of active X.